# Symfony2, server side PHP classes for http calls and user logged

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony

In my server, a Symfony2 application is running.

Moreover, the server has a folder where some PHP classes are put. These classes are used for utility purposes and are used by http calls (in particular by using AJAX from the pages of my website). For instance, a PHP class is used for file upload (see next figure).

[image: The schema of the current use of the php utility classes]

The http call should be done by one of my webpage (and everything would be ok), but it could also be done from an external website. The latter http request is supposed to be a malicious one.

Hence, I need to insert such a code in the php class to check if the user is logged in (even not is it has a specific role). **How to do that by considering that I'm using Symfony2?**

PS: I underline that *the control must be done in a generic PHP classes*, not in a Symfony2 controller!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to check on the external script, if the user is logged in on your application?

Comment: No! In the PHP class (server side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use common PHP solutions, like setting a Session variable as suggested by **Stony**, however there is something in Symfony2 session that I'm missing. Even if a variable is defined in a Symfony2 controller, the `$_SESSION` object seems not to include it.

Hence, I tried to follow the "*controller way*", as suggested by **Stony**.

Here follows what I did. Suppose to have to run the PHP class "FileUpload.php" through an http call. The PHP file has the class *FileUpload* to be used. In my case, the call was done through AJAX. Hence, I should do something like:

```
<script>
  load('http://path/to/fileupload.php')
<script>
```

where `load()` is an hyphotetical Javascript function for AJAX calls.

Of course, the initial idea was to include all the controls in FileUpload.php. *I wan't able!* So what?

Simply, create a controller in Symfony2. Then create your action. E.g.

```
public function fileUploadAction(){
    //control if user is logged and has required role as usual with Symfony2
    $uploader = new \Path\To\\FileUpload();
    //do something with object uploader

    exit(0);//Symfony will not require an answer, but you did what you needed
}
```

Of course, the script in the webpage has to be updated:

```
<script>
  load("{{path('route_to_fileUploadAction')}}")
<script>
```

Remember to put the FileUpload.php in a secured folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is when you ask Google. There two posibilities. You can use Symfony2 or you use your script. The best way is when you implement your fileupload in your Symfony application and call this.

There is a complete section in the SF2 documentation about [Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html). You should read it carefully and then you can implement it.

Without an auth you cannot safe your user information in a SESSION. But if you have a login on Symfony you could set a SESSION variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['loggedOn'] = true;
```

Then ask in your fileupload script if the session is set.

```
session_start;
if($_SESSION['loggedOn'] == false) {
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What the `session_start;` line is for?

Comment: I guess it had to be `session_start()` ;) Without starting session you won't be able to get `$_SESSION` data

Comment: When you don't start you session you have local variables and not your complete global session. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: @Stony Are you sure that in Symfony2 the PHP call to `$_SESSION['loggedOn']` works? Because the classes doesn't work. Of course `session_start()` works.

Comment: You can use the internal session system of symfony it do the same $this->get('session')->set('variable','value');

Comment: @Stony Are you sure that this call can be done in a whatsoever PHP class? I suppose it can be done only in a Controller.

Comment: You should make your auth in symfony ;) so you need a controller. But i said its better you implement all in SF2

Comment: I'm trying to let your solutions works, but, apart from session_start(), the $_SESSION['loggedOn'] doesn't work. However, I get a look in a template to see if the 'loggedOn' value has been stored correctly and the answer is 'yes, it is stored correctly'.

Comment: I followed your ideas and I provided a solution to the problem. Thanks